# Images Not Appearing in Firefox/Chrome; Ok in IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, image

I have a few jpeg images on this page that, for some reason, do not show up in either Firefox or Chrome, but fine in IE 8 and 9. If I click the image URL in Firefox browser source, it shows up just fine.

http://www.chemoutsourcing.com/banners.php

The paths are correct, using a mix of both full and relative urls, and am using the IMG tag correctly. I'm very baffled at the simplicity of this.

```
<div style="margin:5px 0;">
                        600px by 160px<br />
                        <img src="http://www.chemoutsourcing.com/images/banner_ads/mainheader_2013_600x160.jpg" border="1" width="600" height="160" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin:5px 0;">
                        600px by 160px<br />
                        <img src="images/banner_ads/mainheader_Pharma_600x160.jpg" border="1" width="600" height="160" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin:5px 0;">
                        160px by 600px<br />
                        <img src="images/banner_ads/mainheader_2013_160x600.jpg" border="1" width="160" height="600" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin:5px 0;">
                        160px by 600px<br />
                        <img src="images/banner_ads/mainheader_Pharma_160x600.jpg" border="1" width="160" height="600" alt="" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: So... how can we help if you don't post some code?

Comment: Added. But I also attached the url of the page for source code purposes as well.

Comment: I'm also baffled. I don't see anything wrong.. works in Chrome but not in FF for me

Comment: I know, right?  I have no idea what the hell the issue is.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox (I can see all the images on chemoutsourcing.com/banners.php)

Comment: @unor, what about in Chrome?

Comment: I tested it in Firefox, Chromium and Epiphany: all browser display all four images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solutions occur by accident.

I tried viewing this page in Chrome Private mode, and they appeared fine. So that means...

The browser extension AdBlock was reading the images' subfolder "banner_ads" in the source and treating them as 3rd party content to block.

Once I rename the folder, the issue should go away on its own.

Comment: This worked for about 90% of the images in the folder. The few holdouts I will look into but I'm not nearly as concerned now. They may be corrupted for all I know.

Answer (score 1):

I used inspect element on chrome, and it shows the following inline styles attached to all the img elements:

```
display: none !important; 
visibility: hidden !important;
opacity: 0 !important;
background-position: 600px 160px;
```

That can't be right.

Comment: Ok, I see that, too. But where is it inheriting this from?

Comment: I can't say, because they are appearing as inline styles. Not inherited from any css file. Maybe some javascript code is doing this?

Comment: Plus, using the Resources Tab on chrome, I saw that the browser isn't actually receiving the images at all!

Answer (score 0):

Change directory name to ensure the word 'ads' isnt there. For example: if image source is src=images/**ads**/your_pic.png then rename the folder 'ads' to anything but not 'ads'. for example - src=images/**visitor_image**/your_pic.png

This should work, if not then its not about browser, its about your re-directions.
p.s. ignore syntax mentioned here, use your own.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Figured out the picture not showing correctly was named .JPG while others were named .jpg. Renaming apparently fixed the problem for me.